# How to properly create a pandas dataframe with the given data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following experiment data:

```
experiment1_device = 'Dev2'
experiment1_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
experiment1_timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 6]
experiment1_task = 'Oil Level'
experiment1_user = 'Sean'

experiment2_device = 'Dev1'
experiment2_values = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
experiment2_timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
experiment2_task = 'Ventilation'
experiment2_user = 'Martin'

experiment3_device = 'Dev1'
experiment3_values = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
experiment3_timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
experiment3_task = 'Ventilation'
experiment3_user = 'Sean'
```

Each experiment consists of:

1. A user who conducted the experiment
2. The task the user had to do
3. The device the user was using
4. A series of timestamps ...
5. and a series of data values which have been read at a certain timestamp, so `len(experimentx_values ) == len(experimentx_timestamps )`

The data is currently given in the above format, so to speak single variables, but I could change this output format if need. For example, if it would be better to put everything in a dict or so.

The expected output format I would like to achieve is the following:
[image]

`Timestamp`, `User` and `Task` should be a `MultiIndex`, whereas the device is supposed to be the column name, and empty (grey) cells should just contain `NaN`.

I tried multiple approaches with `pd.Dataframe.from_records` but couldn't get the desired output format.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since the data are stored in all of those different variables it will be a lot of writing. However, you should try to store the results of each experiment in a DataFrame (directly from whatever outputs those values), and hold all of those DataFrames in a list which will cut down on the variables you have floating around.

Given your variables, construct DataFrames as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': experiment1_timestamps,
                    'User': experiment1_user,
                    'Task': experiment1_task,
                     experiment1_device: experiment1_values})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': experiment2_timestamps,
                    'User': experiment2_user,
                    'Task': experiment2_task,
                     experiment2_device: experiment2_values})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': experiment3_timestamps,
                    'User': experiment3_user,
                    'Task': experiment3_task,
                     experiment3_device: experiment3_values})
```

---

Now join them together into a single DataFrame, setting the index to the columns you want. It looks like your output wants the cartesian product of all possibilities, so we'll reindex to get the fully `NaN` rows back in:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).set_index(['Timestamp', 'User', 'Task']).sort_index()

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values(i).unique() 
                                  for i in range(df.index.nlevels)])
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

---

```
                              Dev2  Dev1
Timestamp User   Task                   
1         Martin Ventilation   NaN   5.0
                 Oil Level     NaN   NaN
          Sean   Ventilation   NaN  10.0
                 Oil Level     1.0   NaN
2         Martin Ventilation   NaN   6.0
                 Oil Level     NaN   NaN
          Sean   Ventilation   NaN  11.0
                 Oil Level     2.0   NaN
3         Martin Ventilation   NaN   7.0
                 Oil Level     NaN   NaN
          Sean   Ventilation   NaN  12.0
                 Oil Level     3.0   NaN
4         Martin Ventilation   NaN   8.0
                 Oil Level     NaN   NaN
          Sean   Ventilation   NaN  13.0
                 Oil Level     NaN   NaN
6         Martin Ventilation   NaN   9.0
                 Oil Level     NaN   NaN
          Sean   Ventilation   NaN  14.0
                 Oil Level     4.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply with a solution. Somehow I seem to be doing something wrong as I'm getting the error "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!". As in my real data, every user is basically performing every task with each device. As a side question, is there somehow the possibility to crunch the NaN values a bit to have fewer?

Comment: @user7638008 if you just need one column, as it looks like you could just name the columns `'Dev'` when you make the DataFrame, so it would be `'Dev': experiment1_values` in the dict that makes the DataFrames

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a simpler way, but you can create sub-dataframes:
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 6]]).T
df1.columns = ['values','timestamps']
df1['dev'] = 'Dev2'
df1['user'] = 'Sean'
df1['task'] = 'Oil Level'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]).T
df2.columns = ['values','timestamps']
df2['dev'] = 'Dev1'
df2['user'] = 'Martin'
df2['task'] = 'Ventilation'

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]).T
df3.columns = ['values','timestamps']
df3['dev'] = 'Dev1'
df3['user'] = 'Sean'
df3['task'] = 'Ventilation'
```

merge them into one:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['timestamps','dev','user','task','values'], how='outer')
df = df.merge(df3, on=['timestamps','dev','user','task','values'], how='outer')
```

and create the aggregation:

```
piv = df.groupby(['timestamps','user','task','dev']).sum()
piv = piv.unstack()     # for the columns dev1, dev2
```